# Enlarge images by clicking (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a second class to be added to each image by clicking on it and the image will be the size defined in the second class:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.photo_main>img').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('size_img');

  }, function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('.photo_main > img');
  });
});
```

```css
.photo_main {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5rem auto 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo_main>img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
}

.size_img {
  width: 850px !important;
  height: 550px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photo_main">

  <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/200" alt="">

</div>
```

Comment: you should use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass` or `removeClass`. You should use one function only to attach to the event. And you should fine tune the selector from `.photo_main` to `.photo_main img`

Comment: Hello. I tried this too and it didn't work. Can you edit the script code for me so that it works correctly?

Comment: I posted an answer with that exact strategy and it works as expected instead. Maybe I'm not seeing what doesn't work according to your judgment. Can you be more clear please?

Comment: Why do you have two functions inside of click? The first one is not executed because of how the comma operator works and `'.photo_main > img'` is not a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass` or `removeClass` to add/remove a class based on the fact if the element already has it or not.

https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Then you should fine tune the selector from `.photo_main` to `.photo_main img` because you want the click event handler to be on the picture itself so that inside the handler, `$(this)` will be the img element you want to address to toggle its class.

In the end you should use one function only to attach to the event.

One minor adjustment was removing `!important` using a selector that wins the specificity over the default size.

Here's your code with the expected behaviour working, where if you click on the picture it will enlarge its size and if you click again it will revert back to its initial size:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.photo_main img').click(function() {   
    $(this).toggleClass('size_img');
  });
});
```

```css
.photo_main {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5rem auto 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo_main > img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
}

.photo_main > .size_img {
  width: 850px;
  height: 550px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="photo_main">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/gcff1c3f39b9717427535f7ba5991535b7e545da97477390c0135ea11e9cf49ad0ec4887befe05915ec29f9e91bb9022c6780f91059ecfcba12094d3d47df934917143a73a8faeeec06fcdad681bcc960_640.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```